# Query and Follow Owner Relationship on Tasks

Tags: soql, relationships, tasks

I actually can't believe I've not come across this before now, but is there a way of following on the `owner` relationship on a `Task` to get some other field on the `User` object?

For an example, say on the `User` object there is a custom field called `MyField__c`, and I want to query that while querying tasks:

`select Id, Subject, Owner.MyField__c from Task`

Seems easy, but the `Owner` field is one of those polymorphic lookups peculiar to tasks and activities, as tasks can also be owned by a calendar. If you create a formula field you can follow the relationship using this syntax:

`Owner:User.MyField__c`

which again, is something I've not seen until now but it's easy to see that `:User` is qualifying the relationship type. This syntax does not parse in SOQL, so the question is, **is there an alternative syntax that does work?**

Obviously I can just create the formula field and query by that, but I'm curious to know if there is a way of properly traversing this relationship in SOQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the TYPEOF operator. You can have multiple WHEN clauses in the SELECT, one for each valid type.

Example:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, 
TYPEOF Owner
 WHEN User THEN Owner.MyField__c
END
FROM Task
```

Additional information can be at [SOQL Polymorphism](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html).

Comment: Chris Bland showed me this shortly after posting. I don't want to move the goal posts but I actually wanted to filter by that field in the WHERE clause which can't be done with TYPEOF right now.

Comment: True. You'd either need a formula field to indicate type, a preliminary query, or to filter on the object's prefix. Is there anything on IdeaExchange to allow TYPEOF in inner queries?